# How to solve for points in a region of a plane?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, list-manipulation, vector-calculus

I have three points in 3D Cartesian space:

```
A = {-0.154, -0.246, -0.439}; 

B ={-0.0055, -0.3945, -0.3895}; 

C= {-0.154, -0.444, -0.241};
```

that all lie on the plane with the equation: `1x + 1.5y + 1.5z = -1.1815`

The region of interest is bounded by the vectors AB, AC, BC.

I'd like to generate a list of coordinates that lie both on the plane and that fall within this bounded region.

Any help is greatly appreciated on how to approach this problem!

Comment: What do you mean by "a list of coordinates"?

Comment: There are an uncountable infinity of points inside a triangle. How do you want to select a finite set of them?

Comment: Ever heard about [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system)? If not, you might give it a shot...

Answer (score 4):

Use [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint) and [`Triangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Triangle) (or [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon)):

```
RandomPoint[
    Triangle[{{-.154,-.246,-.439},{-.0055,-.3945,-.3895},{-.154,-.444,-.241}}],
    10
]
```

> {{-0.113334, -0.366351, -0.34576}, {-0.142944, -0.361738, -0.330633}, \
>   {-0.117064, -0.338707, -0.370917}, {-0.0205711, -0.396208, -0.377744}, \
>   {-0.14849, -0.390776, -0.297898}, {-0.120295, -0.292451, -0.415019}, \
>   {-0.13287, -0.402038, -0.297049}, {-0.132239, -0.354835, -0.344672}, \
>   {-0.125268, -0.283741, -0.420414}, {-0.114952, -0.36908, -0.341952}}